# Not able to Use Bean method in Camel Route

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

This is my route class.

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Value("${spring.enablelog}")
    public boolean enablelog;
    
    @Value("${spring.enableroutepolicy}")
    public boolean enableroutepolicy;
    
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
                
        CronScheduleRoutePolicy routepolicy = new CronScheduleRoutePolicy();
        routepolicy.setRouteStartTime("StartTime");
        routepolicy.setRouteStoptTime("StopTime");
        routepolicy.setRouteStartTime("StartTime");
    
        from("activemq:queue:inputq")
        .setProperty(Enablelog, constant(enablelog))
        .choice().when(exchangeProperty(Enablelog).isEqualTo(True))
            .bean(MyRoute.class, "setlogProperties('*', 'Request', 'Pending','Received Input message')")
            .process(logProcessor).endChoice()
        .process(msgProcessor).split().body()
        .toD("activemq:queue:waitq")
        .choice().when(exchangeProperty(Enablelog).isEqualTo(True))
            .bean(MyRoute.class, "setlogProperties('*', 'Response', 'Waiting','Response message waiting to be delivered')")
            .process(logProcessor).endChoice()
        .end();

        
        if (enableroutepolicy == true) {
        from("activemq:queue:waitq").routePolicy(routepolicy).noAutoStartup()
        .toD("activemq:queue:outputq")
        .choice().when(exchangeProperty(Enablelog).isEqualTo(True))
            .bean(MyRoute.class, "setlogProperties('*', 'Response', 'Success','Response message delivered')")
            .process(logProcessor).endChoice()
        .end();
        } else {
        from("activemq:queue:waitq").toD("activemq:queue:outputq")
        .choice().when(exchangeProperty(Enablelog).isEqualTo(True))
            .bean(MyRoute.class, "setlogProperties('*', 'Response', 'Success','Response message delivered')")
            .process(logProcessor).endChoice()
        .end();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void setlogPoperties(Exchange exchange, String msgtype, String status, String statusMessage ) {
        
        exchange.setrPoperty("MessageType", msgtype);
        exchange.setrPoperty("Status",status);
        exchange.setrPoperty("StatusMessage",statusMessage);
    }
     
}
```

In this Route I have two routes

1. From InQueue to WaitQueue
2. From WaitQueue to OutQueue.

First route is always activated and I am activating the second route according to the requirement. In the second route I am not able to call .bean() and pass the params to the setlogPoperties(). I am new to the camel and not sure how to fix this. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem might be that 'enablelog' and 'enableroutepolicy' are not getting picked up from your property file and as the default value of boolean is false your code is unable to reach setlogPoperties().

You have annotated the class as a **@Component**. So in order for **@Value** to retrieve values from the property file, please make sure you are either defining a [**@PropertySource** annotated in this class](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation#using-value-with-setter-injection) itself or you are creating a [bean for this component in a separate **@Configuration** annotated class](https://www.journaldev.com/21448/spring-value-annotation#spring-value-example).